# In an Ant build script, how do you check for the existence of a file or directory as a dependency for a task?

Tags: ant, build, dependencies

Getting started on writing my first build script. I dont get the whole dependency thing. This kind of make sense when your compiling say java and you need the object files to create a jar. But what about if you just want to verify the existence of any file or directory thats not part of a compile task?

Ive been able to use **available** but I dont know how to use the result of that as a dependency for a task

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With something like this:

```
<project name="foo-bar" basedir=".">
    <target name="bar" depends="foo" unless="isAvailable">
     <echo message="file is not available" />
    </target>

    <target name="foo">
      <available file="${basedir}/path/to/file.java" property="isAvailable"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

- The "bar" target depends on the "foo" target.
- When "foo" is executed, it checks for the presence of the file.
- If it exists, it sets the `isAvailable` property.
- The "bar" target will only execute and echo the message if `isAvailable` is not set.

You can also put the `<available>` at the "root level" of your build(outside of a target, as a direct child of the `<project>` and it will get evaluated before any of the targets are run:

```
<project name="foo" basedir=".">

    <available file="${basedir}/path/to/file.java" property="isAvailable"/>

     <target name="bar" unless="isAvailable">
     <echo message="file is not available" />
    </target>
</project>
```

Comment: This is great, but how do you use this in a true/false sense? What if isAvailable is false?

Comment: The property will only be set if the file exists (true).  If the property is not set (false) then it will not trigger the `unless` condition.  If you want to explicitly set "true" and "false" for the values, you can control that with `available` attributes, but you will need to check which version of ANT you are using. Older versions do not check the value of the property, they only evaluate whether or not it was set as the true/false, so if the property is set with a value of "false" it would satisfy the true() condition. I believe newer versions of ANT will recognize "false" as false().

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test if a file exists, look at [`available`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/available.html)

Comment: But then once you use available and set a property to true how do you use that as a dependency for a target?

Comment: Read http://ant.apache.org/manual/targets.html : "A target also has the ability to perform its execution if (or unless) a property has been set"